# Quotation and comma help

Tags: commas, quotations, quotation-marks

I haven't been able to find a straight answer if I am properly writing this sentence:

> “What’re you staring at, huh? Got something you wanna say?”, piques the guard.

Soooo, I was taught to use a comma after a quote, but I'm not so sure that is correct. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use two punctuation marks with a quote, so no comma is needed here.  [If a quote ends with an exclamation point or a question mark, you don't use a comma.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53394/how-to-punctuate-an-embedded-quoted-question-within-a-declarative-sentence)

> "Why is grammar so hard?" he asked.
>   "Grammar is easy!" she exclaimed.

---

As an aside, you're using *pique* in a very nonstandard way.  [It means something like "to raise someone's interest or curiosity"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pique), and it's always used transitively, like

> The attitude of that guard piqued my curiosity.

You can't just say "he piqued".

Comment: In researching this I'm finding a lot of mixed advice about how to punctuate quotations in British English.  I think OP's example is of an *older* BrE style that is no longer in use, but I have yet to find any definitive guide on punctuating quotations.  Jay's answer in ELU seems good, but since it lacks external references, I don't know if I'd take it as absolutely correct.

Comment: Hey, I super appreciate the feedback, I questioned my usage of "piqued", too. As you can tell, English isn't my strongest subject... but I am trying to improve! Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was an older style of BrE, too. Thanks for the feedback, Andrew!

Comment: I thought that was the current BrE style. It's not? (Not being facetious, btw—I'm honestly asking.)

Comment: @spoko  Apparently not anymore, at least not in the various sources I checked.  There are only a very few cases where multiple punctuation marks are okay, such as an quoted exclamation in the context of a question, *Did the teacher really shout, "I can't take it any more!"?* and some British periodicals seem to have adopted the simpler American style of putting the comma inside the quotation marks even when it's not part of the quoted text.  As I mentioned, it would be nice to find a definitive guide to current BrE punctuation.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, no, I wasn't referring to the multiple punctuation. I was referring to the comma coming outside the quotation marks. Btw, why do you say that putting it inside is simpler? Even as an American, I can't see that. I've always thought it was a little strange to put something inside the quotation marks that isn't actually part of the quotation.

Comment: @spoko  it's simpler because it's a consistent rule.  The BrE practice of putting it inside some times and outside other times requires more thought.

Comment: @Andrew I thought they always put it outside.

Comment: @spoko  inside when part of the quote itself, *"I would love to go to the dance," she said, "but I haven't a thing to wear!"* and outside if not, *I know there is a song about "other people's problems", but I don't know what that means.*

Comment: @Andrew OK. I guess I see how you're describing that as simpler. But I'm now even more convinced that the BrE way of doing it makes more sense. :/

Comment: @spoko  Ha, well, as with most things related to English, the British also think their system is superior  :)